# Airplane Elevator Trim Tab - Why is it effective

Tags: aerodynamics

The trim tab is deflected downward, which deflects the elevator control surface upward, which then causes the airplane to pitch 'up'. (and vice versa)

But why does it work that way. Why doesn't the relative wind push the control surface back down again?

(edited once for clarity)

Comment: I'm a little uncertain of this, but it could be because the control surface is "balanced". Part of it extends forward of the hinge. Also because the trim tab is at the back edge, where it has more leverage.

Comment: Would [aviation.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: I believe I have the answer from a discussion with a CFI. The trim tab is located at the rear of the elevator and as such it has more leverage. A deflection of the trim tab up will create a force to drive the elevator down. These forces balance each other

Comment: Ignore the comment above..cant delete it.. time expired..

Comment: Answer: The elevator will be pushed downward by an upwardly deflected trim tab. The small trim tab has more leverage and can therefore deflect the larger elevator control surface down a good bit before they up and down forces are balance. 
With the elevator down, the camber is increased and lift is therefore increased. Result is that the nose of the aircraft is pitch downward.

THANK YOU everyone for your input. I really find this discussion useful

Answer (score 1):

> Why doesn't the relative wind push the control surface back down
>   again?

But it does, however, some additional lift at the trailing edge from the downward-deflected trim tab remains and prevents the full return to the earlier position. What the trim tab does to the elevator, the elevator in turn does to the whole aircraft: Changing its pitch attitude.

See it this way: Before, the elevator was flying at its force-free angle. Then the added trim tab deflection changed the local pressure distribution on the elevator (in the case of a downward deflection it adds lift), so the elevator assumes a new equilibrium position. This new position is found when the lift change on the elevator just compensates for the newly added lift by the tab. Of course it must go trailing-edge up now.

[image: Trim tabs]

Trim tabs (picture [source](http://www.eaa1000.av.org/pix/albatross/tailtrim.jpg))

Comment: @Brian: The comments are not meant for thank-you notes. Better upvote good answers and accept the one which helped most.